# How can I create general model for UITableVIewCell ？

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I have a custom UITableViewCell.It's going to be used by multiple Tableviews.So it gets a different model.
Can I create a Generics model?. Just like

```
MODProductListCell<T>: UITableViewCell { 
    var molde: T? 
}
```

But when I use this cell. It crash. I don't know what happened.

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MODProductListCell", for: indexPath) as? MODProductListCell<Any> else {fatalError()}
```

It crash

So the question is do I have other ways of creating generic models or is there anything wrong with what I'm doing right now.

EDIt:
My cell is created with XIB, Look like:
[image]

Comment: Why are you using `MODProductListCell<Any>`? Use the actual type that you set in your storyboard. You also need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] to make it on topic. Are you using storyboards/xibs? If yes, you need to include a screenshot of your storyboard/xib setup.

Comment: Generic `T` and `Any` are not related. Generics are not covariant.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Because there will be errors:
"Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'MODProductListCell"

Comment: `T` is not a concrete type, that's the generic type parameter. You need to set the concrete type. If that's not known or is changing for each cell and hence cannot be set from storyboard, then you need to drop your generic implementation.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thank you. I will try use protocol to create model.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making `UItableViewCell` Generic, make ur models to follow protocol. All models want to show data in `UItableViewCell` need to follow a common protocol

```
//Resource protocol is used to display for cell used in table view cell

protocol ResourceProtocol {
    func snippet()
    func title()
    func image()
    func url()
}

//Model1
class ArtistResource: ResourceProtocol {
    func snippet() {
        //return snippet
    }
    
    func title() {
        //return title
    }
    
    func image() {
        //return image
    }
    
    func url() {
        //return url
    }
}

//Model2
class SongResource: ResourceProtocol {
    func snippet() {
        //return snippet
    }
    
    func title() {
        //return title
    }
    
    func image() {
        //return image
    }
    
    func url() {
        //return url
    }
}

//Model3
class AlbumResource: ResourceProtocol {
    func snippet() {
        //return snippet
    }
    
    func title() {
        //return title
    }
    
    func image() {
        //return image
    }
    
    func url() {
        //return url
    }
}

class TableViewCellView {
    var resource: ResourceProtocol
    
    init(source: ResourceProtocol) {
        resource = source
    }
    
    func loadCell() {
        //show snippet
        //show title
        //show url
        //show image
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer gives me another way of thinking